# If "Olympics" is singular, why does it use "were"?

Tags: word-usage, subject-verb-agreement

[Source](https://www.irishtimes.com/news/world/asia-pacific/beijing-a-city-transformed-a-decade-after-landmark-olympics-1.3588996)

> But the Olympics **were** really only a staging post in a much more
>   fundamental reshaping of the Chinese capital.

On [blog.esllibrary.com](http://blog.esllibrary.com/2012/07/29/olympics-singular-or-plural/), I found "Olympics" is a singular:

> #### Decision time:
>
> We at ESL Library decided to go with **“the Olympics” + singular verb** and **“the Olympic Games” + plural verb**. Basically, “the Olympics” is a collective noun like team or United States, and usually takes a singular verb. “Games,” on the other hand, is a plural noun that should take a plural verb. It’s possible to consider “the Olympic Games” as a collective noun, but “the Olympic Games **is**...” just doesn’t sound right to me. “The Olympic Games **are**...” sounds much better!

Comment: Take your pick: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Olympics+is%2COlympics+are&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2COlympics%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2COlympics%20are%3B%2Cc0

Comment: The blog shows how variable the definition of "Olympics" can be. For example, the author writes "each Olympics" at one point, apparently implying that the Olympic Games held in 2016 (for example) constituted "one Olympics." But _Olympics_ can also refer to the entire series.

Comment: The key phrase is "we decided". ESL Library is one group of people. Other groups have decided different things, or just flip-flop on a whim. So the premise of the question is flawed (though the question itself may have value regardless).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The word *Olympics* is plural. It's also a shortened expression of the *Olympic* ***Games***.

The history of the games is discussed on the official [website](https://www.olympic.org/ancient-olympic-games/history-old):

> Olympia, the site of the ancient Olympic Games, is in the western part of the Peloponnese which, according to Greek mythology, is the island of "Pelops", the founder of the Olympic Games. Imposing temples, votive buildings, elaborate shrines and ancient sporting facilities were combined in a site of unique natural and mystical beauty. Olympia functioned as a meeting place for worship and other religious and political practices as early as the 10th century B.C. The central part of Olympia was dominated by the majestic temple of Zeus, with the temple of Hera parallel to it.

The authors of the article you referenced are free to use whatever style they choose, but I would argue that they are in the minority.

Comment: That is the first result of searching "Olympics plural" :D

Comment: Does that mean that it should be the Olympic's, given that it's a contraction? I'm only half kidding, but I'm definitely going to start using that to the people in my life irritated by misplaced apostrophes.

Comment: Is **gymnastics** plural too?

Comment: @Yann just because it is a contraction does not imply an apostrophe. The plural of "games" goes to the word "Olympics". It is not like "it's" where the letters of the following word, "is" or "has", is dropped. It is not that the letters "game" are dropped here.

Comment: @rexkogitans That really just shifts the problem, though. Much like the word "semantics" in other contexts, in the context of the Olympic Games, "games" is often used in journalism on its own as a singular noun. "These games were...". The only valid conclusion, IMO, is that this is completely subjective.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit “These games were ...” is plural. If it were singular, it would read “This games was ...”.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Er brainfart sorry I meant to write "The games was". Like "the games this year was...". In isolation yes it looks ridiculous, but it's what happens. Actually I think the noun may be capitalised. "The Games this year was..." I'd have to go look up an example to be sure. But in the meantime I'll just repeat that I definitely see it being treated singular. :)

Answer (score 21):

"We at ESL library decided to go with..."

I don't think you can really take such a decision as an authoritative source.

As they say "Olympics" is a collective or, more precisely, uncountable noun. Their mistake is a lack of awareness that uncountable nouns, despite their name, can still either be singular (eg rice, equipment, research) or plural (jeans, police). The Olympics are of the latter group.

Comment: Jason Bassford's answer is quite correct, but this answer is better.  "The United States" is a phrase that is similar.  "The United States" can refer to the singular collective (and so "is" would be appropriate), or as a pluralistic group (so the word "are" would be appropriate).  "The United States of America are 50 states that have a governor, two federal senators, and other common characteristics."  Also, "The United States is a country of 50 states.  Each of these states unite to a large country, but still have their own individual actions."

Comment: This is the better answer.  Language is (perhaps regrettably) fluid.  "The olympics" is now used to refer to the singlular grouping of many games.  But, thanks to that pesky "s" on the end, the grammatical rules are much more complicated to apply.